# Guzzle – no request in Symfony accessing Parse.com API

Tags: symfony, parse-platform, guzzle

I would like to use Guzzle to create request.
My settings looks like this:

```
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/class');
$request->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$request->setHeader('X-Parse-Application-Id', 'id');
$request->setHeader('X-Parse-REST-API-Key', 'key');
$response = $client->send($request);
```

And always, I get

```
Client error response
[status code] 401
[reason phrase] Unauthorized
[url] https://api.parse.com/1/classes/class
```

I'm sure I have correct ID and KEY. Also, there is no API call in debug toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when i access the url it prompts me with basic auth

so i think you have to do sth like

```
$request->setAuth($user, $pass);
```

before sending